# How do I create a progress bar on a webview in a fragment with a navigation drawer? my language is kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-webview, android-fragmentactivity, android-progressbar

until now I am still confused to display the progress bar in the webview navigation drawer, I will be very grateful for the answers
this is a MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    displayScreen(-1) }
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        { drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START) } 
    else { super.onBackPressed() }
}
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> return true
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item) }
}
fun  displayScreen (id: Int){
    val fragment = when (id){
        R.id.nav_home -> { Home () }
        R.id.nav_login -> { login0 () }
        else -> { Home () }
    }
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.relativelayout, fragment)
        .commit() }
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    displayScreen(item.itemId)
    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true }
```

}

and this home.kt aka Home : fragment() =

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?
    { val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.home, container,
        false)
    val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview) as WebView
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/")
    myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
    (WebViewClient())
    return  view }
```

Comment: or give me the answer how to add loading progress bar at any touch/click in activity or event at android kotlin